# how to integrate my iphone app with twitter api?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I need to tweet and also retrieve tweets.is any api available for this, any sample application or code .

.thank you in advance

Comment: Yes there is, you just need to search.

Comment: Have you tried searching on this link ? http://www.google.com

Answer (score 2):

This is now built in to iOS5. Take a look at the [Twitter Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Twitter/Reference/TwitterFrameworkReference/_index.html)

Answer (score 1):

if you're planning to support iOS version before 5.0, have a look on the MGTwitterEngine, http://mattgemmell.com/2008/02/22/mgtwitterengine-twitter-from-cocoa/

Answer (score 1):

see this link may be it help to u

https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone/

here some code

```
- (void)viewDidAppear: (BOOL)animated {

    // Twitter Initialization / Login Code Goes Here
    if(!_engine){  
        _engine = [[SA_OAuthTwitterEngine alloc] initOAuthWithDelegate:self];  
        _engine.consumerKey    = kOAuthConsumerKey;  
        _engine.consumerSecret = kOAuthConsumerSecret;  
    }   

}
if([_engine isAuthorized])
    {  


        [_engine sendUpdate:@"your posting data"];


    }
```

import authtwitterengine

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Benjie, you should try and use the Twitter API that's built into iOS 5. Here's how: http://www.peterfriese.de/the-accounts-and-twitter-framework-on-ios-5/